# Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to find project file at path: C:\BuildAgent\work\aa2455b503370bdd

Tags: teamcity-7.0

I am not able to set .sln file path for my project in team city. Even the solution file path explorer is failed to show my path which is avaiable in Mercurial. I have given the right path in VCS for pull changes and it shows other files but it does not show my .sln file by the solution file path explorer. And when i try to run it shows followring error
 Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to find project file at path: C:\BuildAgent\work\aa2455b503370bdd\myproject.sln

Comment: I was putting wrong branch name for mercurial ..issue solved

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error, for me it was because the VCS Root had somehow become unattached, probably when Build Templates were copied between projects, but either way it's worth checking that you have a current and valid VCS Root configured (Admin -> [Your Build] -> Version Control Settings)